# How to change ng-click state through javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to let a code works just if a conditional is true

```
if document.getElementByClass('toggle').style.visibility == 'visible'
```

it should be like if in my page it were written

```
ng-click="toggle = !toggle"
```

But how do I select that toggle state in my javascript file?

EDIT: more info

```
div(ng-controller='ViewsCtrl', ng-class="toggle ? 'nav-open' : 'nav'")
  .container
    .logo
      img(src='images/logo.png')
      span Motto

    ul(ng-class="toggle ? 'menu-open' : 'menu'")
      li
        a(ng-click="changeView('home')") Home
      li
        a(ng-click="changeView('products')") Products

    button.toggle(ng-click='toggle = !toggle') Menu
```

controller

```
appControllers.controller 'ViewsCtrl', [
  '$scope'
  '$location'

  Ctrl = ($scope, $location) ->

    $scope.changeView = (view) ->
      $location.path view
      if document.getElementByClass('toggle').style.visibility == 'visible'
        $scope.toggle = !toggle
      return

    return

]
```

Comment: try ng-click="function(toggle){toggle = !toggle}"

Comment: No they don't work :-/

Comment: You don't need to handle the toggle logic in your controller, and basing the state of `$scope.toggle` on the `visibility` style of the element is slightly backwards. You should toggle the visibility of your element based on the state of `$scope.toggle` somewhat like: `if($scope.toggle) element.style.visibility = 'visible'`. I would suggest to use `ng-class` in your view instead of handling this in your controller. This is not what is usually considered as controller logic. Please review my answer implementing `ng-class` to toggle classes.

Comment: @WebWanderer well I see your point, but I'm using this unsual (maybe even wrong?) way to achieve what I'm needing because this should only trigger if the webpage layout is in mobile mode, otherwise those menu links would mix mobile and desktop styles (a hamburger navigation with a black background (mobile) that covers a horizontal and top-of-the-page navigation (desktop))

Comment: If you wanted your answer to be based off of being in "mobile" or "desktop" mode, then you should have stated so in your question. To be completely honest with you, I'm not even sure what you are attempting to do now, nor do I understand the unorthodox syntax that you are using in your controller.

Comment: Conditional layouts should be handled by your stylesheet with @media queries.

Comment: @WebWanderer in fact I asked just about how to "grab" what's inside ng-click. And about that syntax, are you referring about that is .coffee and not .js or just that I'm bad about scripting? Cause if it's the latter you would be right, I'm still learning, hence I'm here.

Comment: Sorry Emanuele, I've never seen .coffee before actually. It's messing my head up a little bit. I was simply saying that as I learn more about what you are trying to do, I begin to think that you are not taking the best approach. You say that you need to trigger the `toggle` both outside of the nav and within the `nav`, yet I saw nothing in your question relating to the nav, otherwise I would have engineered an answer for you around it. If you could provide more information, I could provide a better answer for you. Despite my lack of knowledge in .coffee, I am very seasoned in js and angular.

Comment: Maybe you should try `button.setAttribute('ng-click', 'toggle = !toggle)` in your first code snippet. I'm not sure how to translate that to .coffee, but that is how you set the `ng-click` attribute on a `button` from .js.

Comment: Well don't worry, coffeescript is just a preprocessor like jade, makes things faster.
By the way, yes I need just that, inject it but don't know how: how do I inject it inside a link? I need that it runs when I click on a link so the nav collapses, something like `[grab the link that I'm clicking].setAttribute('ng-click', 'toggle =! toggle')`

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="button" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" value="{{toggle?' Hide':' Show'}}"/>
  <div ng-show="toggle">shown</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As already written (1 min before u replied), I'm not in needing of this directive because I'm using this code for switching between two classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to toggle between classes, you will want to use `ng-class`.

By using `ng-show`, as mentioned by the other answers, you will not actually set the elements `visibility` to `hidden` or `visible`, but you will instead set the elements style `display` to `none` or `inherit`. In order to set the element's `visibility` style, I would suggest declaring your own classes and using `ng-class`.

```html
<style>
.not-visible {
 visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
 visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="button" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" value="{{toggle?' Hide':' Show'}}"/>
  <div ng-class="{'not-visible' : !toggle, visible : toggle}">shown</div>
</div>
```

Remember, we need the apostrophes around the class name `not-visible` because it has a hyphen. You can read the documentation on ng-class [**here.**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: Yes but I asked how to control that toggle with my javascript code because I have to let it run only if a statement is true

Comment: And it will run only if the statement is true, even without being controlled by **your** javascript. By using `ng-class` it is controlled by Angular's javascript. The expression within `ng-class` might have funny syntax, but the statement ends up the same: `if(!$scope.toggle) element.className = 'not-visible' else element.className = 'visible'`

Comment: If you run the code snippet I've provided, you will see that the element's class changes based on your toggle condition, just as you are attempting to do. This is the Angular way.

Comment: I'll provide code so that you can do this in your controller, but I would not suggest doing so. This is not what the controller is meant for and breaks the organizational purpose of Angular.

Comment: I know but I need to trigger that toggle with a button outside the nav AND inside the nav (after clickin a link, the nav collapses)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing the logic in your controller versus in the ng-click like so:

```
$scope.changeView = {
    class: 'menu-closed',
    toggleMenu: function() {
        $scope.changeView.class = ($scope.changeView.class === "menu-closed") ? "menu-open" : "menu-closed";
    }
};
```

And your html would be:

```
<ul ng-class="changeView.class"></ul>
<button ng-click="changeView.toggleMenu()">toggle menu</button>
```

This will keep your HTML clean and keep all logic within your controller, where it should be.

Here is an example showing the above: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mejjRN

Comment: I would disagree, to a certain extent. Logic like this does not belong in the controller. In the link function, sure, but not the controller. Having logic in your HTML such as `toggle = !toggle` is frowned upon, but it's such a simple statement that no one would complain about it, people do it all the time. I was trying to state a way to reach the simplest answer while creating the least amount of working parts, using what Angular provides us to solve the problem in the simplest fashion.

Comment: @WebWanderer I'm a full believer that the HTML should be clean as possible and logic should be delegated to the Controller or a Directive. Of course this being Angular, there are several ways of doing the same thing. Even Angular's own Controller docs delegate something similar to the Controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani You can add the `ng-click="changeView.toggleMenu()"` to any item you want to toggle the menu. So you would add it to the menu buttons as well which will collapse the menu once you click it.

Comment: I'll also add, doing it this way allows for better code reusability. Instead of changing the classes on everything in your HTML, you can just change it in the controller and it updates everywhere you placed it in the HTML.

Comment: @Shane what if I have to change two classes rather than one? I have to do that -open thing to menu and nav

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani Not sure what you mean. You could added a second toggle for the different classes. I updated the codepen above, you can now click the button to open the menu and click the first element to open a sub element.

Comment: @Shane no no no, I need that this `toggle = !toggle` will be triggered by clickin a hamburger menu button AND when clicking the link, but just when in mobile because while in desktop these menu links will no more be stacked in a column, they will be inline (and the hamburger button will be hide)

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani That's something that you can control via the CSS using Media Queries. It can still toggle the classes but you control what the classes do in the CSS with MQ's. That is your best option, as adding a resize watch with angular would be overkill.

Comment: @Shane I can't control when to trigger a script through CSS, can I? I need that just when my MQ enable the mobile layout.
And how is it possible that if I write `a(href="#!/", ng-click="toggle = !toggle") Home` it works but if I move that outside of it (through a script and calling it with `ng-click="toggle()"` it does not work anymore?

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani You don't have to just call it on mobile. All you're doing is toggling a CSS Class which you control the styles for the class in the CSS file. So you can keep the toggling function there for all sizes but only have the open/close styles in the mobile MQ. Creating a watcher for a resize event to look for mobile would be overkill.

Here's another codepen showing this, just resize the render pane to below 400px: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoPqeX?editors=110

Comment: @Shane yes that I MUST call it on mobile.. I need that when I click on a link INSIDE that ul all the nav will collapse. With your script I don't collapse the nav by clicking on a link (if this will explain better, the nav covers all the page when expands)

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani Please re-read everything i've said, I don't think you're truly understanding it. I've already given you instructions on how to accomplish what you're looking to do (3rd reply from top) but here is another example showing exactly that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYxyOE 

Collapse the render pane until the `toggle menu` button shows up and then click a link.